# Can I use an animated shield with the Mage Armor spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, shield

My question is an extension of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103006/can-a-sorcerer-paladin-use-an-animated-shield-without-any-casting-drawbacks/103008#103008).

**Does the *animated shield* count as being armored for the *mage armor* spell?**

Based on *mage armor*'s description (emphasis mine):

> You touch a willing creature who **isn’t wearing armor**, and a protective magical force surrounds it until the spell ends. The target’s base AC becomes 13 + its Dexterity modifier. **The spell ends if the target dons armor** or if you dismiss the spell as an action.

I'd assume you would have to cast *mage armor* after activating the shield and when you retrieve the shield you lose the *mage armor*, effectively reducing *mage armor*'s time durability to a single combat.

To counter the possible duplicate: I am asking about **the *animated shield* magic item**, not the 1st-level *shield* spell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Mage Armor stack with Shield?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44439/does-mage-armor-stack-with-shield)

Comment: @Marq Not the same at all, added an edit to question to elaborate.

Comment: Oops, misread that as ".. stack with _a_ shield".

Comment: Hmm Correct me if I am wrong but a Warlock with Armour of Shadows, Shield and Animated shield could have potentially 20+Dex AC right?

Comment: @MatthewPerryman I don't know about the warlock class, but sorcerer paladin could use mage armor+normal shield+animated shield+shield of faith spell(concentration)+shield spell(reaction cast) for 13+2+2+2+5=AC24+dex

Comment: @Clarus_Nox, Hmm would mot have though of using a normal shield and animated shield at the same time.

Comment: Related, possible partial duplicate: [Can a mundane shield be used with Mage Armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78429/can-a-mundane-shield-be-used-with-mage-armor)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**A shield is not armor**

The player handbook mentions several times, distinctly, *wearing* armor and *carrying* a shield.

Some AC calculations, such as Unarmored Defense, specifically point out that you cannot carry a shield to apply its calculation, where no such stipulation exists in Mage Armor.

[Here's a similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78429/can-a-mundane-shield-be-used-with-mage-armor/78441) for everyday, non-animated shields.

Answer (score 4):

The *animated shield* will "protect you as if you were wielding it". This means that it works as though it was in your hand, without you having to use a hand to hold it.

As asked in ['Can a mundane shield be used with Mage Armor?'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78429/can-a-mundane-shield-be-used-with-mage-armor?noredirect=1&lq=1), a shield **does** stack with *mage armour*.

Your AC will be 13 + Dex mod + 2 (from the shield).